# How to add an empty line/space in Lightning App Builder?

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps

I found no way to add an empty line/space between two fields in Lightning App Builder.

Does anyone know how to do it?

[image]

I know it is quite easy to do it with the page layout tool of the object manager, but I am not sure how to do it with Lightning App Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per salesforce standard functionality, its not possible to add line/space between two fields in lightning record pages.

Refer the [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZaaUAF/dynamic-forms-need-blank-spaces-in-lightning-record-pages-for-field-sections)